# Image compositing of two Images

Tags: java, algorithm, image, image-processing, image-recognition

I am trying to solve a problem of compositing two images in Java.  The program will take a part of the first image and past it on the second image. The goal is to make the boundary between the two images less visible. The boundary must be chosen in such a way that the difference between the two images at the boundary is small.

---

**My Tasks:**

To write a method to choose the boundary between the two images. The method will receive the overlapping parts of the input images. This must first be transformed so that the boundary always starts from the left-top corner to the right-bottom corner.

**NOTE:** 
The returned image should not be the joined image but gives which parts of the two images were used.

The pixels of the boundary line can be marked with a constant`(SEAM)`. Pixels of the first image can be marked with integer 0, pixels of the second image with integer 1. After choosing the boundary line, the `floodfill` algorithm can be used to fill the extra pixels with 0 or 1.

**NOTE:** The image can be represented as a graph  whereby each pixel is connected with its left, right, top and bottom neighbor. So using the flood fill will be like depth-first search.

The shortest path algorithm must be used to choose the boundary in order to make it small.

**NOTE:**  I can not use any java data structure except Arrays (not even ArrayList)

---

Guys, am new in this area and am trying to solve it. What steps must I follow to solve this problem?  or a pointer to a tutorial

Comment: *"I can not use any java data structure except Arrays (not even ArrayList)"* Is this homework?

Comment: Noo it isn't. I would have marked it homework if it is so

Comment: So why then can you not use any Java data structure (besides arrays), or even a structure of your own device?

Comment: that is the requirement of the question am trying to solve and want to do it just as it is. Can you help me with the initial steps i can follow? For instance how do i represent the images as graghs? etc..

Comment: This question is not about compositing, it is about segmentation.

Comment: Add images to illustrate & you stand a greater chance of getting an answer

Comment: I would say it is on images recognition, only in the narrow area.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it so:

Choose the width of the border checked. At your will.
 1. find the maximal possible shift in pixels.  That is D.
 2. For all possible shifts in the square (+-D,+-D) find the k (correlation quocient) for the border. The border is taken in the middle of the shift. 
 3. The shift that has the largest k is the best. Let it be taken for granted.
 4. Now begin to move the border, checking it by "k" the same way. Find the place of it. Done.

If D is large and the process is long, do it in 2(or more) stages. On the first stages the step of counting k is large, the last stage has step of 1. You could also use previous filtering.

If the border or relative images' position could be turned, the algorithm doesn't change principally - only add to it trying for the best k among different slightly turned positions and later - turned border, too.