# Compositing of two images in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, image, image-processing

I am trying to solve a problem of compositing two images in Java. The program will take a part of the first image and past it on the second image. The goal is to make the boundary between the two images less visible. The boundary must be chosen in such a way that the difference between the two images at the boundary is small.

**My Tasks:**

To write a method to choose the boundary between the two images. The method will receive the overlapping parts of the input images. This must first be transformed so that the boundary always starts from the left-top corner to the right-bottom corner.

**Note:** The returned image should not be the joined image but gives which parts of the two images were used.

The pixels of the boundary line can be marked with a constant (SEAM). Pixels of the first image can be marked with integer 0, pixels of the second image with integer 1. After choosing the boundary line, the floodfill algorithm can be used to fill the extra pixels with 0 or 1.

**Note:** The image can be represented as a graph whereby each pixel is connected with its left, right, top and bottom neighbor. So using the flood fill will be like depth-first search.

The "shortest path algorithm" must be used to choose the boundary in order to make it small.

**Note:** I cannot use any Java data structure except Arrays (not even ArrayList) or I can use my own defined data structure.

I am new in this area and am trying to solve it. What steps must I follow to solve this problem?

My main issue is, how do I represent the images as graphs in Java code (for instance with arrays or my own data structure)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've gone out on a limb here and tagged this as homework, the way it's formatted would definitely suggest that it is!

Comment: I need answer and not whether it is homework or not. I would have tagged it homework if it is.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462577/image-compositing-of-two-images

Comment: "The shortest path algorithm must be used to choose the boundary in order to make it small." this is what might give people the impression it's homework. Generally on job tasks you don't get instructions on what algorithm you must use in your implementation. So if it's not homework it could be an interview question :)

Comment: So you want to tell me that we are not suppose to answer past examination questions or what. If am answering past questions don't i have to be honest and write the requirements as they are? Why are people sooooo obsessed with homeworks and et.....  If you know the answer you help the person. Homework or not doesn't matter. It is the help you give that matter. Whether someone thinks it is homework or not is not important

Comment: It's not that people don't want to help it's that when a question is about homework/interview question you need to specify. The general accepted way of answering those questions is different then on regular questions see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for some clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what can be an answer to your "Main issue" part of the question.

You have to represent the images pixels as graph and also you have a restriction to use Java array only. Well if you look at a 2 dimensional array which you will need to use represent the pixels of the image, it can be used as an graph as well just that each item in the array will only have data value (pixel color) and the attached node to the current node can be calculated using the below formula:

```
Current pixel : [X,Y]
Top pixel : [X,Y-1] 
Bottom pixel : [X,Y+1]
Left pixel : [X-1,Y]
Right pixel : [X+1,Y]
```

NOTE: X and Y are index in the 2D array. Also, when incrementing/decrementing X or Y to calculate neighbor pixel you need to make sure that you dont't overflow/underflow the boundary of the image i.e decrementing should not cause the value of X/Y to be < 0 and increment should not cause the X to go beyond width of image and Y to go beyond height of image.

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Comment: thank you very very much for your straight answer. I'm new in Image Compositing/Processing stuff so am struggling. A little question here. How am i going to fill the 2D array with the image pixels? Am i going to use java functions to read the images pixel by pixel? I need help in that area. thanks

Comment: Added a link to the answer which is a tutorial for working with Images in Java

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a varying opacity level at boundary to the center of image.So the edges cannot be identified.

see http://sreejithvs999.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/transparent-image-composition-in-java-fixing-an-image-over-another-with-changing-opacity-or-alpha-of-pixels/

where one image is fixed over another with changing transparency.